# iOS Dynamic Table View Cell Height Without UILabels

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to use this feature without using text related views? This would be to not have to calculate the height, but instead let the cell self-size using subviews with constant height constraints, and eventually changing those height constraints at runtime.

Comment: Here is the most basic example, however it breaks when running. In it I have not even changed the constraints.

https://github.com/slswalker/TestDynamicCellHeight

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to handle dynamic cell height changes in a table view is through `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in `UITableViewDelegate`. You can grab the height from the subviews but you have to link that value to the index path of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you could build a tableviewcell with dynamic height.

1.use constraints to configure your tableviewcell's subviews

2.add a line of code In viewdidload method:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

3.in some cases you must add another line of code In viewdidload method:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40 //or any value other than your tableviewcell's height in IB.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.
First Add constraints to subviews and add the following code in .m file.

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
  }

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

Comment: Whether I do this or set the property on the Table View, constraints will still break. I have an example above that demonstrates the problem in it's simplest form.